# Can someone improve my code? what's wrong?

Tags: sockets, compiler-errors, syntax-error, serversocket

I have a problem in compiling, it's a "unexpected type required variable; found: value" and
"incopatible types" my code is here:

`

```
String sCL;
BufferedReader br = null;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("banned.txt"));
providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 10);
connection = providerSocket.accept();
```

`

```
while((sCL = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if ((br.readLine()) = (connection.getInetAddress().getHostName())) {
        sendMessage("baned");
    }
    else {
    //some code here.
    }
}
```

Errors are in `.readLine()` and `.getHostName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you need a double-equals here?:

```
if ((br.readLine()) == (...
```

Comment: @CzarekRasiński: No, this answer is wrong, in light of the extra code you've posted.  Ravi's answer is right.  I'll delete this answer, once I know you've seen this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has three bugs on the same line:

1. Using `=` instead of `==`
2. Doing a `readLine()` twice
3. Comparing `String`s with `==`

   if (sCL.equals(connection.getInetAddress().getHostName())) {

And I'm hoping that `getInetAddress()` isn't `NULL` now! :)